# Why can't we conditionally render opening and closing tags only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I'm wanting to render a piece of content, but certain factors may dictate whether it is rendered as a `<span>` or as an `<a>`, I would end up needing to write like:

```
<>
    {someCondition
        ? <span>My content</span>
        : <a ...>My content</span>
    }
</>
```

but what I'm wondering is why we can't render in this way instead, to shorthand/speed things up

```
<>
    {someCondition ? <span> : <a ...>}
        My content
    {someCondition ? </span> : </a>}
</>
```

When I try to run this snippet I receive only an error at the point I'm attempting to render the closing `</span>` tag...

Comment: Because jsx is not a string, it's a tree of objects

Comment: Apart from making your code very hard to follow, there are much better ways.

Comment: How does it even compile? It is not even a valid syntax and the compiler refuses to build such a code.

Comment: If the actual underlying goal is to avoid duplicating "My content" then that could be refactored into its own variable and you'd just re-use that variable when using the first approach above.  But for *the question asked* as to why JSX doesn't support the second approach, it simply doesn't.  "Why" isn't really relevant.  (You could look at it the other way and research what it would take to support that approach and if that effort justifies the use case presented here.  I suspect it doesn't.)

Comment: Hi @physicsboy, as per HTML standard specification, every element must have closing tags except few self closing tags. so even for rendering engine it is necessary to close tags along with content. Here when react renders `{someCondition ? <span> : <a ...>}` it try's to find and implement the closing tag. which is not available so it is considered as broken element and throws error. My clarification might be insufficient but it is my humble try to explain it. You can read this article for more details. https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/not-closing-jsx-tags-properly. I hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You could somewhat get the desired output by defining the tag first before creating the JSX:

```
const Type = (someCondition) ? 'a' : 'span';
return <Type {...props} />
```

---

React Demo showing this:

```js
const Example = () => {
  
    const [someCondition, setSomeCondition] = React.useState(true);
        
    const Type = (someCondition) ? 'a' : 'span';

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <Type>{`I'm rendered as an <${Type} /> because the 'someCondition' is ${someCondition}`}</Type>
            
            <br /><br />
            <button onClick={() => setSomeCondition(p => !p)}>Toggle someCondition</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
a    { color: blue; }
span { color: purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This is how I do it,  but for those using Typescript, please remember to use the correct case,  eg.  `TheComponent` & not `theComponent`..

Comment: Yeah,  `Type` is fine, it's just the capital letter at the start, if it's lowercase Typescript will complain.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically that syntax rules don't allow you to do so. In JSX syntax, each opening tag needs to have a corresponding closing tag. The shorthand you proposed doesn't follow that structure, which makes this syntacticly invalid.

If you don't want to use your first example, you may try using a helper component to handle the conditional rendering:

```
function ConditionRenderer({ condition, content }) {
 return condition ? <span>{content}</span> : <a>{content}</a>
}

// And in your component
<>
  <ConditionalRenderer condition={yourCondition} content="Your content" />
</>
```

Comment: I'd make the `content` prop named `children` so you can use `ConditionalRenderer` to wrap content.